# PyQt signal: set variable

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I have a signal, which just needs to do one thing: if emitted assign a variable a given value. It seems stupid to create a method for this, so I was thinking: Is there a way to do something like this:

```
self.myButton.clicked.connect(self.someVariable = None)
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for a lambda.

Comment: FYI, stackoverflow doesn't like signatures/signoffs. It takes up unnecessary space. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lambda:

```
self.myButton.clicked.connect(lambda : self.someVariable = None)
```

Notes:

1. `self` is referenced upon slot call, so you might want to do:

   `self.myButton.clicked.connect(lambda self=self: self.someVariable = None)`
2. Some widget send signals with parameters, and you have to put them in lambda definition.

   `self.myButton.clicked.connect(lambda checked=False, self=self: self.someVariable = None)`

UPDATE:

Assignments are not allowed in lambda, so you will have to use real function or something like this:

```
self.myButton.clicked.connect(lambda self=self: setattr(self, 'someVariable', None))
```

Comment: I get: SyntaxError: lambda cannot contain assignment, I tried with both versions you mentioned

Comment: Ah, yes, You are right. This won't work. I guess you will have to use real functions, instead of fiddling with something like: `self.myButton.clicked.connect(lambda : setattr(self, 'someVariable', None))`

Comment: What about using `functools.partial`? It could look like: `self.myButton.clicked.connect(functools.partial(setattr, self, "someVariable", None))`